# meet or met in a sentence when in future

Tags: tense

If you ever (meet/met) her, tell her I said that.

which one is correct when tell someone the sentence above?

Answer (score 1):

"If you ever meet her, tell her!" should be the correct simple version (for a future action). Because when you already met her, in the past, you won't be able to report her anything I said you would not have done yet if you are not supposed to have another date.

But we have: "if you ever met her, you know she's fine."

Otherwise, if you already met her, you know her, so you may be able to tell her what I said *on your next meeting with her*.

Your question has 2 senses.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever (had already) met her, (you'b be able next time to) tell her I said that.

But if you have to meet before to say something to another, and not had already done, the *rendez-vous* is a **condition**. So we'd have to say : They would have met before...